# Get the email field of an user with Lookup Fields

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-email

I have a model with a field associated to a user with ForeignKey, I need to send an email to that user when the user do an action, my question is not about to send the email instead is how to get that email. App works like that: User pick one of a lot of options (clicking in a button) that button call the ID of the model that contains the user_id through a DetailView, and when that button it's clicked send the email. My view:

```
class NotificationEmail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'email.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        p = Articles.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        for articles in p:
            print (articles.user_id__email)     
            to = articles.user_id__email
            html_content = '<p>This is your email content...</p>'
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('You have an email',html_content,'from@server.com',[to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content,'text/html')
            msg.send()
            return super(NotificationEmail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Models:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

My questions basically is how can I get the email of the user that has the ID of that model? Im trying with `articles.user_id__email` I suppose that this is the way to look up the field, I know that is wrong, but.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think we need to see your Articles model. Please add that.

Comment: Assuming it has a `user` field then would it not be `articles.user.email`?

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey Hi, that was pretty simple, solution was as you said `articles.user.email`  anyway, I have added the model. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Articles class has a user field then you need to do this to get the associated user's email:

```
articles.user.email
```